# wkhtmltopdf failed error code -11 odoov8

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, odoo-8, wkhtmltopdf

I have problem with printing pdf files in odoo 8

Every time I hit print it give me this massage

```
Report (PDF)

Wkhtmltopdf failed (error code: -11). Message: Error: Failed loading page http:///tmp/report.tmp.yWknzr/report.footer.tmp.UYfr2X.html?page=1&section=&sitepage=1&title=&subsection=&frompage=1&subsubsection=&isodate=2017-04-17&topage=1&doctitle=&sitepages=1&webpage=/tmp/report.tmp.yWknzr/report.body.tmp.QXmK5d.html&time=11:47 AM&date=4/17/17 (sometimes it will work just to ignore this error with --load-error-handling ignore)
QPaintDevice: Cannot destroy paint device that is being painted
```

I have tried the solutions in this topic

https://www.odoo.com/nl_NL/forum/help-1/question/wkhtmltopdf-failed-error-code-11-75795

And it is still not working any one have a solution to this problem?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I may be wrong, but it sounds like there are too many open files, did you try to increase the limit in `/etc/security/limits.conf`?

Comment: thank you for your reply, I tried your suggest put it still throw me the error

Comment: It was worth a try, good luck!